# IndexError: index 2048 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

---

My code below is giving me the following error

```
"IndexError: index 2048 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2".
```

I am quite new so I do not have any idea about how to solve this.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
X=[]
X1 = np.load('class_1data_model1.npy')
X2 = np.load('class_2data_model1.npy')
X_data = np.append(X1,X2,axis=0)
Y_data = X_data[0:,2048]
X_data = X_data[:,0:2048]
x_tr,x_ts,y_tr,y_ts = train_test_split(X_data, Y_data, test_size=0.2,random_state=10
```

Comment: the axis has a size 2 and you're treating it like it has a size of 2048, the error can't be clearer than that

Comment: first check size/shape of `X_data` before you get `Y_data`. You should also display `X_data` to see what you have after `append()`. It seems `X_data` has only 2 columns but you try to get column number 2048

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
X1 = np.load('class_1data_model1.npy')
X2 = np.load('class_2data_model1.npy')
X_data = np.append(X1,X2,axis=0)
nrows, nclos = X_data.shape
Y_data = X_data[:,2048].reshape((nrows,1))
X_data = X_data[:,:2048]
print('X_data.shape: \t{} (OLD)'.format((nrows,ncols))
print('X_data.shape: \t{} (NEW)'.format(X_data.shape)
print('Y_data.shape: \t{}'.format(Y_data.shape) 

### Now perform train_test_split.
```

Comment: I tried This but SyntaxError: invalid syntax comes against these two lines  .....print('X_data.shape: \t{} (NEW)'.format(X_data.shape)
print('Y_data.shape: \t{}'.format(Y_data.shape) ....can  you plz help me..i am new inn python.
Thanks

Comment: Yes I tried it but again this error comes---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c8f31da39c7e> in <module>()
     48 X_data = np.append(X1,X2,axis=0)
     49 nrows, nclos = X_data.shape
---> 50 Y_data = X_data[1:,2048].reshape((nrows,1))
     51 X_data = X_data[:,:2048]
     52 #print('X_data.shape: \t{} (OLD)'.format((nrows,ncols))

IndexError: index 2048 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

Comment: Please share some test data that people can test with. This is not your test-train-split. This the data you provide for anybody to replicate the problem. Without that not much can be achieved.

Comment: What are the shapes of X1, X2 and X_data to begin with?

Comment: I have images dataset and after the feature extraction, the file saves in .npy.now I don't know What are the shapes of X1, X2

Comment: Check the shapes with `X1.shape` and `X2.shape`. You need clarity on the shapes of these arrays before concatenating/merging/stacking them.

Comment: yes, I have checked the shapes and the output shows In real numbers on the line ..like,-0.75 -0.50  -0.25   0.00  0.25  0.50  0.75  1.00.

Comment: What is the type of X1 and X2: try type(X1) and then type(X2)?

Comment: I would suggest you share some dummy data as an example. Also try X1.size and X2.size. But X.shape does not give you something in fraction. Something is off. Without the datanot much can be done.